# Neo4J modifying nodes ignored

Tags: database, neo4j, nosql

I'm using this code for opening a database:

```
GraphDatabaseAPI graphdb2 = (GraphDatabaseAPI) new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("D:\\test\\neo4j\\data").setConfig(ShellSettings.remote_shell_enabled, "TRUE").
        setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable,
        USERNAME_PROPERTY + "," + TITLE_PROPERTY + ","
        + NAME_PROPERTY + "," + LABEL_PROPERTY + "," + TYPE_PROPERTY).
        setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.relationship_keys_indexable,
        USERNAME_PROPERTY).
        setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing, "true").
        setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.relationship_auto_indexing,
        "true").
        newGraphDatabase();
ServerConfigurator config;
config = new ServerConfigurator(graphdb2);
config.configuration().setProperty(
        Configurator.WEBSERVER_PORT_PROPERTY_KEY, 1234);
srv = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper(graphdb2, config);
srv.start();
graphDb = srv.getServer().getDatabase().getGraph();
registerShutdownHook(graphDb);
```

However, when my app stops running, all of the modification is ignored.

Why is that?

Comment: I do not see any examples of 'modifying' in your source code.

Comment: its starting code . after this i'm creating 5 nodes .

Comment: I understand that, but I would like to se an example of how you do that.